# Display all rows in a Sheet iff cell in a separate Sheet is true - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Situation: I have 2 sheets where I am working in.

- Sheet1: Has the point metrics of all the Google Form responses for each person. There are 4 Forms. This sheet has 4 columns with that users' score and one Boolean (True/False) column called "Passed?" that's meant to identify if the user scored higher than 75% (among many other metrics that I'm leaving out). Example below.
- Sheet2: Is *supposed* to only list the names of the highest point scorers, so I can send them a reward or special message. I do this process manually currently.

Question: How might I be able to pull in every row of cells to access just specific cells in that row (ie. "Email" & "Score") of a different Sheet, based on a true or false column? How can I automate this process of identifying the winners and putting them in Sheet2?

[image]

Expected Result:
In Sheet 2, I include the email, first name, last name, and score.
[image]

I just have a general idea of how I want to do it:

- First fill in "Email" based on "Passed?" column in Sheet1, then repeat for "Score".
- Then for the "names" columns, I do an index+match to get those based on "Email" from one of the Form responses sheet linked in this Spreadsheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the layout of your sheets in screenshots; you can try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET ID","Sheet1!A:L"),"SELECT Col2,Col10 Where Col12=TRUE")
```

- 

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was able to import the emails and scores with this query. And I imported the names of the students with an index+match. Thank you so much!